# Codename One - Start drag operation on longPointerPress

Tags: drag-and-drop, codenameone

Is there a way to start **drag operation** in not predefined way?

Abstract example using long pointer press event:

```
public void longPointerPress (int x, int y) {
    methodToStartDragAndDropOperation (this, blablabla);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this with the current API, we support drag regions which are draggable areas within the component but not long press gestures right now.

A hack that might work is using `setDraggable(false)` and in longPress doing something like:

```
super.pointerReleased(x, y);
setDraggable(true);
super.pointerPressed(x, y);
super.pointerDragged(x, y + convertToPixels(3));
```

Comment: It is impossible to scroll container filled up with draggable components. You want to scroll - you perform drag instead. I thought that another fine solution is to clamp the drag region of draggable components to leave some space for scroll gesture in the right side of screen without shrinking draggable components, but overriding getDragRegionStatus has no effect - even if I make it to always return DRAG_REGION_NOT_DRAGGABLE the drag is the same as it was before overriding.

Comment: Sorry, I had to override isDragAndDropOperation(int,int). Messed everything up.

Comment: I didn't test that, what got messed up?